# Multiply reading of document references from Firestore using tasks

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Map of references which I read from Firestore. these refs lead me to documents that I'm willing to use their data to create an instance of my class 'Contact'.

In order to do that I've created a list of tasks which every task of it uses its ref to read from Firestore and retrieve the needed data.

Once it's all done I use Tasks.whenAll(tasks).addOnSuccessListener() willing to retrive my new array of Contacts.

On this method, 'contacts' is empty and 'data' is full of document references.
I expected `Tasks.whenAll(tasks)` to being called only when all this reading using the refs has completed, however it's being called immediately, therefore - nothing happens.

```
private void createContactArray(final ArrayList<Contact> contacts, final Map<String, DocumentReference> data) {
        List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final Map.Entry<String, DocumentReference> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            tasks.add(db.document(entry.getValue().getPath()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            Map<String,String> contactDetails = (Map<String, String>) document.getData().get(entry.getKey());
                            Contact contact = createContact(contactDetails);
                            if(contact != null){ contacts.add(contact);}

                        } else {
                            Log.d(ACTION_FETCH_CONTACT_LIST,"There was ref problem with " + entry.getKey());
                        }
                    }else {
                        Log.d(ACTION_FETCH_CONTACT_LIST, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
        Tasks.whenAll(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                sendBroadcastActionContactList(contacts);
            }
        });
```

I would like Tasks.whenAll to be called once its all finished and not right away. I wish to have a proper explanation for the issue and a decent code that should do the job instead of mine.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about how asynchronous tasks work.  You might want to read through this blog series to better understand how tasks are intended to be used. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html

Comment: Hey @Doug Stevenson, it's a great honor to have you helping me out here.Actually I read it already and this is exactly me trying to implement it right here. At part 4 of your blog, I've noticed you used the very same thing in order to achieve the same goal. Please help me understand the problem. A working piece of code and a bit of an explanation will do the trick. Thank you

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand where you think this code is going wrong.  You can fully expect Tasks.whenAll to execute before any of the other work is done.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your answer, I just want to clarify some data. Isn't Tasks.whenAll should be executed when all tasks have finished? isn't it what it means? as you wrote on your blog on part 4 "Either way, the returned Task will now get triggered for success when all the other Tasks succeed, and trigger for failure if any one of them fails."

Comment: All I wish is that sendBroadcastActionContactList will be called after all other tasks are done so my contact array will really have the needed data (which is being read from Firestore using the tasks).

Comment: No, the callback you attach to the task returned by Tasks.whenAll will be invoked after all the other tasks complete.  The function itself doesn't wait.  It's asychronous just like every other function that reruns a task.

Comment: But Sir, that's the whole idea. The function itself is a void. I don't expect any value to come back from it. My problem is that sendBroadCastActionContactList (the callback) is being invoked only once and it happens straight away, way before any other task finishes. Maybe there's a gap between my understanding and reality. Help me understand it then - how should I validate sendBroadCastActionContactList will invoke only once all tasks have finished their jobs? (Please supply a code example). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the APIs incorrectly.  You should be collecting tasks returned by `get()` into an array, instead of immediately adding a callback to each one.  Pass that list of tasks to Tasks.whenAll().  Then, in the callback for the task returned by Tasks.whenAll, you can examine each DocumentSnapshot results.

Comment: Hey Doug, I really appreciate your answer, Although  I solved it 30 minutes ago. Actually the problem was  Map<String,String> contactDetails that should have changed to Map<String,Object> contactDetails. that way it's working. However, Your answer seems about right - therefore I'll accept it. Thanks a lot and have a great day!